# Can we record the conversation, text, voice and video to save in our server with time log for Google Hangout?

Tags: android, ios, google-hangouts

I want to use the Google Hangout API for Android, ios and Web. And I want to store all the history in my server. Is it possible? If Yes, how we can store it?